# How To Use an Apps Script To "Copy-PasteValue" Dynamic Data In a Google Spreadsheet at a given time?

Tags: javascript, import, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a google spreadsheet that imports and modifies data from an online source that updates every hour. I wish to pull a static copy of the 10pm update from the spreadsheet—essentially a copy-paste special at a certain time. I am using the following Script and set a Time-Driven trigger for 10pm.  The script pulls data from cells N5:N10 of one sheet (which update every hour) and pastes only static values into cells N5:N10 of a second sheet in the same spreadsheet.

`function PasteValue()}`

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

`var data= ss.getSheets()[1].getRange("N5:O10").getValues();`

`ss.getSheets()[2].getRange("N5:O10").setValues(data);`

`}`

When I run the script manually it works perfectly. However, when I set the Time-Driven trigger and close the sheet, all that is imported is a series of static “#######” when I check the next morning.

Does anybody have any insight as to the problem? Or, if anybody has an alternative script or method to automatically copy-pastevalues in google spreadsheets using formulas or scripts, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: doesn't  “#######” just mean the the cell isn't wide enough to display the data, or is it not there even when you paste it into notepad?

Answer (score 1):

When using triggers openById instead of getActive

```
function PasteValue()}
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  ss.getSheets()[1].getRange("N5:O10").copyTo(ss.getSheets()[2].getRange("N5"),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula that you are using (importdata or importhtml) is not calculating when the spreadsheet is not open i.e. user is not online.

You can use a script with urlfetchapp.